# A digraph is strong connected iff it's Eulerian

Tags: graph-theory

I want to prove or disprove that the digraph is strong iff it's Eulerian .One direction I believe is true ,that's , if it's Eulerian then its strong because we have indegree is equal outdegree for each for each vertex so we can have a path to each pair of vertices in both ways .The converse is it true ?

Comment: A digraph with two vertices $a,b$ and three edges from $a$ to $b$ but only one edge from $b$ to $a$ is strongly connected but not Eulerian.

Comment: A tournament with vertices $a,b,c,d$ and edges $ab,bc,cd,ac,bd,da$ is strongly connected but not Eulerian.

Comment: Ok @bof .I've a closely related question .If we say that the digraph is strong does it imply that every distinct pair of vertices is contained in a common cycle?

Comment: @hali Yes, it implies. (And please place space *after* punctuation marks, not before.)

Comment: Consider the digraph with vertices $a,b,c,d$ and edges $ac,bc,cd,da,db.$ It is strongly connected, but the vertices $a,b$ do not lie on a common cycle.